# Regex skipping first match?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match every plain "twitter-like hashtags" in a text, and make hyperlinks of them.

I've had some success, but strangely enough my regular expression `/(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/` is skipping the first case when the string starts with the # sign (the rest are properly matched). If I write anything else before, then the first case is properly matched. It fails only when a # sign appears to be the first character of the string.

Do you know why could it be?

```
function make_hashes_into_twitter_hashtag_urls($content){

           $content = preg_replace('/(^|\s)#(\w*[a-zA-Z_]+\w*)/', '<a href="http://twitter.com/hashtag/\2?src=hash" target="_blank"><span class="color_my_hash">\1#</span>\2</a> ', $content);

           echo $content;

}
add_filter('the_content','make_hashes_into_twitter_hashtag_urls');
```

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by `skipping the first case`?

Comment: Show a sample of the `$content` you're feeding it. It might not be picking up `(^|\s)`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, I think he means the first instance.

Comment: see https://regex101.com/r/rJ9aU8/6 it works.

Comment: @philtune case 1) #thisFirstHashtag won't be picked. #ThisIsPicked #ThisOtherHashtagIsAsWell case 2) Hello. #now #all #hashtags #arePicked.

Comment: @AvinasRaj mh I see, it's strange but it won't work in WordPress...?

Comment: Hmm, well this is showing JS-flavor, not PHP-flavor, but this seems to work: http://regexr.com/3a54i. Look up the rules for beginning of string (`^` in JavaScript)... there might be a difference in the PRCE version.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, you made me think (not easy) and if I use get_the_content() instead of $content to retrieve stuff, it works. Somehow $content (or the_content() for that matter) has something in it that invalidates the regex to match the first instance (this could then be a WP related issue). "What" makes it fail, I don't know.

Comment: It may be that the_content() outputs HTML tags, and regular expressions and HTML are no good friends. get_the_content(), by its side, is harmless as it gets plain text. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/ I'd still appreciate a more accurate answer though so I'll keep exploring and tuned to this.

Answer (score 0):

The `the_content();` template tag outputs HTML and text, and [HTML and regular expressions don't play nice together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/).

I don't know the details about why exactly something like `<p>#`, (which is what `the_content();` was outputing), was making my regex to fail.

I'd love to know why, and how my regex should be - to avoid being trapped (even if, as stated, it's not recommended to mix regex and HTML).

My question is mainly answered, but any additional details on how to hack/workaround this situation would be hugely appreciated!